# Ethnic becoming ethno when making a compound word. Is this a general rule?

Tags: compound-words, ethnonyms

Ethnic becomes ethno when making the word ethnocentrism.

Is this a general rule? Words ending in "ic", let's say XXXic, becomes XXXo when making a compound word?

Or is it even more general? Any adjective words ending in any form becomes XXXo when making a compound word?

Or is it even more more general? Any words ending in any form becomes XXXo when making a compound word?

Comment: It's common but not a general rule. "Political" to "politico-", for instance, but I wouldn't expect it with "economic". Often seen with countries, e.g. "Russian" to "Russo-", though "Chinese" changes to "Sino-". Best option is to search for individual cases: Merriam-Webster lists many combining forms.

Answer (score 2):

Greek-derived adjectives often end in *-ic,* and Greek-type compound words often have *-o-* in the middle. Aside from both types of word formation having a Greek origin, there is no especially close connection between the existence of an adjective ending in *-ic* and the existence of a compound word with *-o-* in the middle. Consider that the compounds *Eurocentrism, androcentrism, heliocentrism* are clearly not derived from nonexistent adjectives **Euric, *andric, *heliic*.

The ultimate source of both *ethnic* and *ethnocentrism*  is the Ancient Greek noun *[ἔθνος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3De)%2Fqnos)* (*ethnos*) meaning variously "host, group, tribe, nation, people".

Ancient Greek used *-ικός* (*-ikos*) as a common adjective-deriving suffix. That Greek suffix is the main (although not only) source of the English suffix *-ic*, and in fact, *ethnic* comes from an adjective that already existed in Ancient Greek, *ἐθνικός* (*ethnikos,* from the noun *ἔθνος* + the suffix *-ικός*). The Oxford Engish dictionary has citations for *ethnic* in English going back to the 15th century.

Words starting with *ethno-* come into English later, so it's possible that the preexisting word *ethnic* played a role in their adoption, but they aren't necessarily directly derived from *ethnic.*

---

Ancient Greek regularly uses the combining vowel *-o-* to form compounds from nouns (although this is often omitted before a vowel). There don't seem to be many compounds from *ἔθνος* in Ancient Greek, and some of the ones that do exist don't show the vowel *-o-* (e.g. *ἐθνάρχης* *ethnarches*). The only word starting in ἐθνο- that I can find in the Liddell and Scott dictionary of Ancient Greek is [*ἐθνοφύλαξ*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3De)qnofu%2Flac), which seems to be an unimportant word that is found only as a gloss. However, the OED entry on *ethno-* says *ἐθνο-* is found as a combining form in Byzantine Greek, citing "ἐθνόμυθος", and says *ethno-* has been used to form new words in German and French since "the second half of the 18th cent." and in English "from the first half of the 19th cent., e.g. ethnographer n."

The Oxford English Dictionary's first citation for *ethnocentric* is from 1861. Some other *ethno-* words with earlier attestations per the OED are *ethnographic* (1805) and *ethnology* (1787).